# using argrument in bash to find a file on a remote server

Tags: bash

I am using Ubuntu 14 and trying to import a file from a remote server. The file is an SQL, and there are many in there.

I am using this script on the local server and it is returning the file name.

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
echo $input

#get the file name of the most recent file
file=`find /home/user/dbBackups -type f -name ${input}"*" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f1,2 -d'_'`

file1=$(basename $file)
echo $file1
```

I have then tried to put this on to another computer and tried to execute it remotely with this.

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
echo $input

file=$(ssh ceta@<servername> -p 12345 `find /home/user/dbBackups -type f -name ${input}"*" | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f1,2 -d'_'`)
file1=$(basename $file)
echo $file1
```

When trying to run the script on the remote server it hangs on the command, and I am unable to "ctrl c" out of it. I think it's the variable inside the find command. If I replace that with a file name it works ok.

I'm fairly new to the world of coding, and this is my first StackExchange post. Hopefully I have given enough detail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With the backticks, you are executing the find command on your *local* machine, not the *remote* machine. You want:

```
remote_cmd="find /home/user/dbBackups -type f -name '$input*' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f1,2 -d'_'"
file=$(ssh ceta@<servername> -p 12345 sh -c "$remote_cmd")
```

But if you want to *transfer* the file, use `scp`

Comment: Many thanks for your response.

I do want to scp the file in the next part.  And I can use the $file as the part needed in the command for that.

or can i use the $remote_cmd in the scp command?

Comment: Also, it seems to be searching only in the home directory of the user.  and not using the path that is issued in the remote_cmd variable after the 'find'

Still have a play thought to see if I can figure it out.